# How do I send only Shift down or only Shift up message?

Tags: vbscript

Judging from the documentation of SendKeys this is not possible. Is there a workaround?

My goal is to remap a mouse button of only one of two mice. I don't think AutoHotKey supports different mice, please correct me if I'm wrong. So I'm trying to use [HID macros](http://www.hidmacros.eu), which uses VBScript.

Comment: You've probably seen this already, but check out https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/44468-eithermouse-multiple-mice-individual-settings/ if not. Good luck!